# How to have Rails Views process HTML tags from database content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok. I know this is very basic. I want to have some basic tags around text content in the database to be processed in the view's rendering.

Basically, I have a model named Page.

```
rails g model Page name:string content:text
```

I want whatever is in the content field to be shown in the view but, if there is HTML in the content field, I want it to be processed not just shown.

For example, in my Page#show view, I may have:

```
<%= @page.content %>
```

Which outputs:

< p >This is my first < b >paragraph< /b >.< /p >

When I want it to output:

This is my first **paragraph**.

Again, please be gentle. I know this is probably pretty basic but I am having a hard time searching for how to do this. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [raw](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw) helper method.

```
<%=raw @page.content %>
```

Comment: what is better raw or html_safe? and what is saffer?

Comment: `raw` calls `html_safe` underneath the hood.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw  .

Answer (score 2):

`<%= @page.content.html_safe %>` if you are safe with it's content.

Comment: I think raw is recommended. Check out this article:
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/