# Allow editing of static pages in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

In my rails app , i have a few static pages. If the text on those static pages has to be changed later, i would have to change the source code and redeploy the app. Is there some way using which me or even someone else ,say a client, can edit the text directly and save it, just like in a cms.
I have heard of rails based cms like refinery cms etc but i want to integrate the static page edit functionality in my app itself. What would be the best way to do this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WYSIWYG editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) and store all the HTML data in your database.

Then load this data on your page. You can also provide a edit form for this data.

- [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)
- [How to have Rails Views process HTML tags from database content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579695/how-to-have-rails-views-process-html-tags-from-database-content)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with storing and retrieving the view code that you want your client to be able to change in and from the database. You can build a separate admin view then where your client can edit the text/html, or go more fancy and integrate something like the [mercury editor](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury).

Answer (score 0):

Mercury editor is pretty popular gem...here are a couple of resources...

http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be mentioned here as well that the CKEditor or TinyMCE would also solve this; as well as the TrixEditor which will be included with Rails 6