# Make Rails process HTML from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first real App i'm creating and deploying. I'm running on `Ruby 2.2.4p230` & `Rails 4.2.5.1` . So I have high_voltage static pages setup for my apps main pages that are basically static, and I would like them to pull content snippets from the database. These snippets will be used across multiple pages or to add in hints to the applications features.

I have also created a `Page` Model by using:

```
rails g model Page name:string content:text
```

To see if I could get anything to render from my `Pages` table, I then tried to use:

```
<%= raw @page.content %>
```

I got all this by following: [How to have Rails Views process HTML tags from database content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579695/how-to-have-rails-views-process-html-tags-from-database-content)

When following this, I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried adding:

```
# app/models/page.rb
def pageParams
    params.require(:content).permit(:content, :name, :id, :created_at, :updated_at)
end
```

This still hasn't yielded me anything. Like I said, I'm very new to rails as this is my first true application, that I do plan on putting into production. I have tried many other methods of getting the html to render there to no avail. Most methods I find no longer work for  `Rails 4.2.5.1`

**How This Must Be Done with High Voltage**

```
#app/controller/Pages_Controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
PageIndex = Page.find_by_name('index').content
end
```

Then in the High Voltage view must contain:

```
<%= PagesController::PageIndex %>
```

You must use the Pages_Controller for calling these in High_Voltage. I tried putting this same code in the application controller, application Helper, and it kept saying High_Voltage NoMethodError. Once i put the code into the #app/controller/Pages_Controller.rb it worked perfectly. That is why I gave credit for the correct answer to Ven. Ven showed me the correct way to do it. But I took it a step further and decided to make a constant rather than a global variable. Steve's answer is also correct and had initially given him credit until I got Vens answer which is the proper method to go about it, according to all Rails documents. Steve provided me an a usable workaround, that works great as well.

Comment: You could explicitly retrieve the record...`<%= raw Page.first.content %>` or `<%= raw Page.find_by(name: "my_page").content %>`

Comment: Thak you so much. I knew i was missing something simple. Now is there a reason I wouldnt want to do this?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn can u repost your answer as an answer so I can give you the credit for it?

Comment: happy to do so.  You wouldn't want to do this for a normal view but high_voltage doesn't give you easy access to a controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to assign `@page`. The `@` prefix denotes class instance variables in Ruby, and Rails views share instance variables with their controller:

```
def high_voltage
  @page = Page.find(params["post_id"]) # find a page by ?post_id= parameter
  # Since you said you want them "static", I guess you can hardcode the name:
  @page = Page.find_by_name("high_voltage")
end
```

This way, the variable `@page` will exist, instead of being `nil`, the crux of your error.

However, I'd recommend instead just using the `show` action of your `PageController` (you can find by name in that action), if all you're gonna do is hardcode a bunch of actions with `Page.find_by_name()` in it.

Note that if `Page.find`, you'll get a 404 (`.find()` will raise a `RecordNotFound`), so you're sure the view code will never get executed if there's no post to display.

---

If you actually want to display the page with different text in case the post wasn't found, you can use `find_by_id`:

```
def high_voltage
  @post = Post.find_by_id(params["post_id"])
  # @post may be nil here!
end
```

And in your view:

```
<% if @post %>
  <%= @post.title %>
<% else %>
  The post wasn't found!
<% end %>
```

---

Finally, a note on the "postParams" code you added:

This is a security mechanism to make sure only certain attributes are settable by the user (i.e. in a "register" form, you don't want the user registering to be able to set its "admin" field).

It should however be placed in the controller, not the model. And it should be used when calling `.new` or `.create` or `.update_attributes` in said controller (actions `create` and `update`, usually).

Comment: Ok so quick question about this in your second version with the find_by_id in my view you tell me to put the at post.title how do I tell this which ID's content I actually want. This is where I get confused going this route rather then going Steves route

Comment: You can use `find_by_name("High voltage")` if you wish :). But if you're generating e.g. a sidebar, looping on pages, you have the ID.

Answer (score -1):

You can explicitly retrieve the record in the view...

```
<%= raw Page.first.content %>
```

or

```
 <%= raw Page.find_by(name: "my_page").content %>
```

Comment: don't SQL in views.

Comment: @ven what about high_voltage views? What's your alternative?

Comment: This is simplest and easiest method. I have tried declaring varaibles gloabally that already call the sql from controllers (as suggested by Ven) but only end with with nil as the response.