# How can I display some texts with tags in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg

I am learning rails these days, and now I am trying to use Wysiwyg editor for editing blog post body.
It was nice to use it, but after saving text and emoji through Wyziwyg, I got the text with tags as below. What I really want is showing everything that I wrote in Wyswyg including emoticons within the area as below.

Do I have to use Wyswyg editor for just displaying this post body as well? Like with editor function disabled? If not so, do I need another kind of gem for that?

[image]
Here is index.html.erb as below

```
<div class="main">
    <section>
        <a href="<%= new_admin_post_path %>"><button class="create-button">Create New</button></a>
        <% if @posts.exists? %>
            <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                <article class="article-summary">
                    <h1 class="article-title"><%= post.title %></h1>
                    <div class="article-content"><%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %></div>
                    <p class="article-created-at"><%= post.created_at.to_time.strftime('%B %e at %l:%M %p') %></p>
                    <p class="article-command"><a href="<%= edit_admin_post_path(post) %>"><button>Edit</button></a> <%= link_to button_tag("Delete"), admin_post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
                    <% if post.image.attached? %>
                        <%= image_tag post.image, class: "article-image" %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= image_tag 'https://placekitten.com/1000/800', class: "article-image" %>
                    <% end %>
                </article>
            <% end %>
            <%= will_paginate @posts, class: "page"%>
        <% else %>
            <h2>There is no post</h2>
        <% end %>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Rails Views process HTML tags from database content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579695/how-to-have-rails-views-process-html-tags-from-database-content)

Comment: Thank you @Amit, but I want to also display the emoticon as well as you see above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`html_safe`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) or [`sanitize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) method on the text from a WYSIWYG editor when you want to render as a html page.

Using `html_safe` could be like this:

```
@str = "<b>Hi</b>".html_safe
<%= @str %>
```

And utilizing `sanitize` using [`rails-html-sanitizer`](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer) gem could be as below:

```
full_sanitizer = Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new
full_sanitizer.sanitize("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
```

According to the documentation of both methods, it is obvious that using `sanitize` is more reliable and recommended:

> It is recommended that you use sanitize instead of this method.

Simple solution using `html_safe`:

```
<%= post.body.html_safe %>
```

Reliable solution using `sanitize`: this method removes background style because it contains `url` method. So, you need to define custom css sanitizer.

Comment: Thank you @Hazhir, but as you can see inside of the body, there is an emoticon in it, and I want to see it as well. It will be much like seeing content in Wyziwig but without editing function.

Comment: I updated my answer. `html_safe` will render emoticon properly. Additionally, using `sanitize` needs defining a custom css sanitizer in your case.

Comment: Thank you @Hazhir. It seemed to display emoticons, but still they are affected by outside of the element (emoticons became really small, and repeatedly displayed).

Comment: Please follow https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp to understand how to adjust the emoticons inside the span.